# How do I equip gear on PC? (player menu hotkey)

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons-dark-alliance

This sounds ridiculous, but my friends and I can't figure out how to equip anything!

According to [this link](https://attackofthefanboy.com/guides/dungeons-dragons-dark-alliance-how-to-equip-items-and-gear/) you "open your character menu", and [this link](https://www.gamepur.com/guides/how-to-equip-loot-in-dungeons-dragons-dark-alliance) says you open your "character sheet", but neither of those seem to be buttons.

On console, you can open it using the "player menu" button *('back' on Xbox controller)*, but, amazingly, there is no option for that in keyboard bindings.

[image: No keyboard binding for 'player menu']

So **how do I open the player menu on keyboard** so I can equip things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the key is <kbd>M</kbd>, with some caveats:

- You **need to be in town to equip anything**
- Sometimes the key takes a few seconds to work, or - in one of the most ridiculous keybinding bugs I've ever seen - sometimes you need to **press another key or move the mouse** before the menu will open

Once in the equipment menu, you *click* on the slot you want to equip to, then *hover* over the item you want to equip.  Sometimes the game won't register the hover, so you need to move the mouse away and hover over it again.  Then hold <kbd>Enter</kbd> for one second to equip.

Yep, you need to repeat that for each equipment slot.  Oof.